# Vue app lifecycle: need parameter from route (for graphQL query)

Tags: vue.js, graphql

I am using the GraphQL + Apollo + Vue. 
In this scenario, user clicks on some item in the list, the detail page opens, and the id of the item is passed on with the `$route`.
The moment the detail page is opened, the GraphQL query is executed.

The problem is that at that moment I can not get the id which I need for the query.

If I am calling the method from `mounted()` I am able to `console.log(id)` there. 
I know that I can put GraphQL fetch as **async** in `mounted()`, but that would probably slow things down.

Code:

```
export default {
    name: "CreatePage",
    apolloProvider,
    apollo: {
       detailAlert: {
         query: GET_ALERT_DETAILS_QUERY,
         variables: {
             //this is where I need the id:
             id: this.$route.params.id,
         },
         options: {
            context: {
               headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  "authorization": CONFIG.accessToken,
               }
            },
         },
         result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
             console.log('We got a result!', JSON.stringify(data.alerts[0].value));
             this.detailAlert = data.alerts[0].value;
         },
         // Error handling
         error(error) {
              console.error('We got an error!', error)
         },
      },
   },
data() {
    return {
    ....
    id: this.$route.params.id,   //this is where it's set
    },
}
methods: {
    getAlertDetail() {
        console.log(this.id)  //I am able to see it here  
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.getAlertDetail();
},
```

Is there way to get the id before `mounted()`?

Comment: Can't you use created()? And if that is not working using the apollo propertie you can try defining the apollo client explicitly and calling the query from your method maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways for load data for certain `id`:
1. You can use `beforeRouteEnter()` hook (and `beforeRouteUpdate()`).
2. You can load data in `created()` hook.

In the first case user waiting for while data will load, in the second case user can see page with default data and after load your real data user will see rerender parts of page.

General information is in [Vue route Data fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation) documentation.